# Ruby aws-sdk gem configuration Hash is converted to String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rubygems

I am trying to use amazon S3 for storing and retrieving files from my rails application, have setup the changes in configuration file for aws_credentials, but what is supposed to by sent as hash to the below configuration.rb file is being sent as string.

Credentials in development.rb in my application is as follows:

```
:s3_credentials => {
  :bucket => "mybucketname",
  :access_key_id => "MYACCESSKEYID",
  :secret_access_key =>"MYSECRECTACCESSKEYID"
}
```

The options object supposed to be a hash is being sent as string like this:

```
"bucket:mybucketname access_key_id:MYACCESSKEYID   
 secret_access_key:MYSECRECTACCESSKEYID"
```

That is causing the issue with the below error:

> /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.64.0/lib/aws/core/configuration.rb:292:in `with': undefined method `inject' for  (NoMethodError)

The part of error occurence in configuration.rb file in the gem is:

```
def with options = {}       
    options = options.inject({}) {|h,kv| h[kv.first.to_sym] = kv.last; h }
    values = supplied.merge(options)
    if supplied == values
      self # nothing changed
    else
      self.class.new(values.merge(:__created__ => @created.dup))
    end
end
```

I have no idea where the object type getting modified, i even tried using the credentials through yaml file but still the same issue. Its working in my colleague's machine in another project, but somehow for my project i am finding difficult with this issue. Advance thanks for any help.

Comment: can you provide a stack trace for how you end up in .with ? Can you clarify: options object supposed to be a hash is being sent as string? Where are you using the :s3_credentials?